# Can you setup a PS3 without a controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I have just bought a used PS3 to use as a streaming media player. I've also bought a PS3 Blu-Ray remote (the one that looks like a TV remote) to use with it.

The PS3 I bought didn't come with a PS3 controller.

I've just powered the PS3 on, and got the setup screen asking me to plug a controller in via USB:

[image: PS3 setup screen]

Is there any way to get past this screen without a PS3 controller?

Comment: It's been many years since I've done this, but I believe the reason it wants you to plug in the controller is that new controllers need to sync with new systems. Are there any instructions with the remote that say how to sync it?

Comment: Also, I've heard about some people having success with using a USB keyboard on that screen. Either way, you'll need *something* to do the setup... You might just want to buy the cheapest used controller you can get your hands on (or borrow one).

Comment: I'm not sure about the PS3 media controller but as far as I remember the PS2 one functioned as a controller and you could actually use it in games however dumb it was to do that. So just try that maybe?

Comment: @DangerZone have added picture of screen. The BD remote instructions talk about going to the PS3's XMB menu to pair the remote, which would presumably need me to get past this setup screen. I've got a USB keyboard and tried plugging in and pressing every key - the keyboard is recognised (e.g. Caps lock light goes on and off) but nothing seems to emulate the "P" key that the PS3 wants...

Comment: In that case, your best bet might be to pick up a used one on eBay/Amazon/craigslist. I'd be surprised if you couldn't get one under $15-20 at this point. And besides, you can get some pretty sweet games for cheap on the PS3 and a controller will come in handy ;)

Comment: @awidgery I assume you've already tried pressing the PS key on the remote, just under the directional keys and above select/start? It seems painfully obvious, but you haven't mentioned trying that yet, per Probst's analogy with the PS2 remote.

Comment: @recognizer Yeah I tried that - nothing. But the issue is that I think the remote uses Bluetooth (not IR) to communicate with the PS3 so it will need pairing up for anything to work

Comment: Pretty sure the windows key is the PS button on a keyboard

Comment: @Probst interesting - the windows key is the only one that does anything at all - but all it does is show a "No entry" symbol at the top right of the screen...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After many helpful suggestions it doesn't look like there's any way you can do this.

I tried:

1. **HDMI-CEC**: This isn't enabled on the PS3 by default (confirmed in the menu system when I finally did get in) and no key on my TV remote had any impact on the PS3
2. **USB keyboard**: No keys had any effect, except the Windows key, and all this did was show a "no entry" symbol
3. **Using the Bluray remote itself**: Doesn't work as it uses Bluetooth to communicate with the PS3 and can't be paired with the PS3 until you're in the PS3's menu system (the BD remote has no mini USB port like a Dualshock controller does which presumably allows the Dualshock to communicate with the PS3 before the Bluetooth pairing happens).

In the end I borrowed a controller from a friend for all of 1 minute - all it took to complete setup, get into the PS3 menu, and pair the BD remote.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an HDMI-CEC control, that might be able to get you far enough to be able to pair the remote. I don't know what the PS button would be, but it might be worth a try

Comment: Tried every key on the TV remote for the Sony TV the PS3 is plugged into. None of them seem to have any effect...

Answer (score 0):

I plugged in a wireless mouse to the usb port and used it to navigate the screen.  Got the controller programmed in a few minutes.  Worked great.

Comment: Can the OP get past the screen he posted an image of using a wireless mouse?