# How can I use a PS4 controller for a PS3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, ps3, controllers, backwards-compatibility

A friend gave me his old PS3 with a broken hard drive, I changed it and when tried to install the firmware, I realize I don't own or could borrow a PS3 controller.

Since PS4 controllers won't work via cable, the only solution that came to my head was to maybe find a way to adapt the PS4 controller so the PS3 could recognize it as one.

I don't really know how I could do that, but maybe the Arduino Uno I have could do the trick. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Doing some investigation online it is definitely possible to use PS4 controllers (including DualShock 4) on PS3. Please read this [link](https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/do-ps4-controllers-work-on-ps3#:~:text=To%20use%20a%20PlayStation%204,with%20the%20controller%20right%20away.) (one of many similar guides) for more details on how - relevant excerpts on the procedure described in the link follow:

"To use a PlayStation 4 controller with a PlayStation 3 console, the easiest approach is to simply connect the controller using a USB cable. Once the cable is connecting the two pieces of hardware, you'll be able to play PS3 games with the controller right away.

How to connect a PS4 controller to your PS3 for wireless use

1. Connect the controller and console with the USB cable and power both on.
2. Open the Settings menu, then go to "Accessory Settings."
3. Click on "Manage Bluetooth Devices."
4. Select "Register New Device" by pressing "X" on the controller.
5. Click on "Start Scanning," and then disconnect the cable from the PS4 controller.
6. Hold the "PS" and "Share" buttons on the controller, and when the lights on the controller start flashing, plug the cable back into it.
7. Highlight "Wireless Controller" on the screen and click on it.
   You should now be able to use your PS4 controller wirelessly with your PS3."

Failing that according to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255934/can-you-setup-a-ps3-without-a-controller) post (found on this same site titled "Can you setup a PS3 without a controller?") it would appear your next best option is to perhaps borrow a controller that can connect to the PS3. Unfortunately, I cannot find information on how you could go about "hacking" the interface to get it operating another way.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! We dont like questions that are just links without actually explaining how because links tend to change/dissapear. To make this answer great, could you transfer the main answering components of the links into your post? Copy pasting bits is fine.

Comment: Certainly. I'll get around to it in a little bit (busy atm). Thanks for your guidance. : )

Comment: I hope the changes are to your collective liking. I'm not sure my answer could ever be great but I thought I'd have a crack given the absence of any other efforts. Please advise me if more edits are required. Thanks for your feedback. : )

Comment: That is way better. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: My pleasure. :)